# Query error in python using mongodb when filter by id

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I trying make a query using a array of ids, I try pass **string** and **objectid** with value but the error persists. The query work in **Mongo Compass** but don't work in python.

**Error:**

```
  File "C:\Users\Brumazzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bson\objectid.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.__validate(oid)
  File "C:\Users\Brumazzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bson\objectid.py", line 202, in __validate
    raise TypeError(f"id must be an instance of (bytes, str, ObjectId), not {type(oid)}")
  TypeError: id must be an instance of (bytes, str, ObjectId), not <class 'dict'>
```

This is the **dict** that I generate to query.

```py
{'published': True, '_id': {'$in': [ObjectId('6535cf44376338765f16f50e')]}}
```